# How to autoinstall config "fill disk" option on Ubuntu 20.04 Automated Server Insall?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 20.04, cloud-init

I'm trying to install 20.04 with an [auto install config file](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/AutomatedServerInstalls?_ga=2.47781351.1997747766.1590431586-155658892.1589400613#The_structure_of_an_autoinstall_config) like this one:

**user-data** file:

```
version: 1
identity:
    hostname: hostname
    username: username
    password: $crypted_pass
```

But the automated install process (leaving everything at defaults) does NOT partition the disk to use all space, even though that seems to be the default setting when I run through the installer manually.

After manually selecting all the defaults, I get this `storage` section from `/var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data`

```
  storage:
    config:
    - {ptable: gpt, serial: INTEL SSDPEKKF256G8L_BTHH85121P8H256B, wwn: eui.5cd2e42c81a42d1d,
      path: /dev/nvme0n1, wipe: superblock-recursive, preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: true,
      type: disk, id: disk-nvme0n1}
    - {device: disk-nvme0n1, size: 1048576, flag: bios_grub, number: 1, preserve: false,
      type: partition, id: partition-0}
    - {device: disk-nvme0n1, size: 256057016320, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 2,
      preserve: false, type: partition, id: partition-1}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: partition-1, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-0}
    - {device: format-0, path: /, type: mount, id: mount-0}
```

However, it's not clear to me what from here I need to include in my user-data file to just select the "fill disk" option?

Comment: Hope you do not mind me changing "preseed" to "autoinstall config" preseed is no longer  available as of 20.04. You might also want to post this on https://discourse.ubuntu.com/c/server The creator of this is there and might not visit AU.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not tried this, but the docs suggest a negative value will 'fill'.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/AutomatedServerInstalls/ConfigReference#storage

> the server installer allows sizes to be specified as percentages of the containing device. Also, a negative size can be used for the final partition to indicate that the partition should use all the remaining space.

#### edit

I tried this out.  Using `size: -1` for the final partition did fill the disk.  I tried using `size: 100%` and `size: -1` for an LVM Logical Volume to use all the available space and it did **not** work.  The installer errored in `align_down` in `subiquity/models/filesystem.py`.

I also tried `100%FREE` but *subiquity* errored on `dehumanize_size`

I also tried removing the size property for the `lvm_partition` because the *curtin* docs say (at https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/storage.html)

> If the size key is omitted then all remaining space on the volgroup will be used for the logical volume.

This does **not** work as *subiquity* errors if there is no `size` property

This is unfortunate as using a percentage for an LVM Volume would be a pretty basic use case

The full storage config I tried.

```
  storage:
    grub:
      reorder_uefi: False
    swap:
      size: 0
    config:
    - {ptable: gpt, path: /dev/sda, preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: false,
      type: disk, id: disk-sda}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 512M, wipe: superblock, flag: boot, number: 1,
      preserve: false, grub_device: true, type: partition, id: partition-sda1}
    - {fstype: fat32, volume: partition-sda1, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-2}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 1G, wipe: superblock, flag: linux, number: 2,
      preserve: false, grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-sda2}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: partition-sda2, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-0}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: -1, flag: linux, number: 3, preserve: false,
      grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-sda3}
    - name: vg-0
      devices: [partition-sda3]
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
      id: lvm-volgroup-vg-0
    - {name: lv-root, volgroup: lvm-volgroup-vg-0, size: 100%, preserve: false,
      type: lvm_partition, id: lvm-partition-lv-root}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm-partition-lv-root, preserve: false, type: format,
      id: format-1}
    - {device: format-1, path: /, type: mount, id: mount-2}
    - {device: format-0, path: /boot, type: mount, id: mount-1}
    - {device: format-2, path: /boot/efi, type: mount, id: mount-3}
```

#### edit 2

I kept digging into this and it seems that sometimes *subiquity* stores disk sizes as a float, which led to the uncaught exception.  I was actually able to work around this by not using human readable format.  E.g. instead of `size: 512M`, use `size: 536870912`.

This is a sample `storage` config that uses the autofill option with property `size: -1` and also  configures a logical volume to fill a volume group with the property `size: 100%`

```
  storage:
    grub:
      reorder_uefi: False
    swap:
      size: 0
    config:
    - {ptable: gpt, path: /dev/sda, preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: false,
      type: disk, id: disk-sda}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 536870912, wipe: superblock, flag: boot, number: 1,
      preserve: false, grub_device: true, type: partition, id: partition-sda1}
    - {fstype: fat32, volume: partition-sda1, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-2}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 1073741824, wipe: superblock, flag: linux, number: 2,
      preserve: false, grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-sda2}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: partition-sda2, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-0}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: -1, flag: linux, number: 3, preserve: false,
      grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-sda3}
    - name: vg-0
      devices: [partition-sda3]
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
      id: lvm-volgroup-vg-0
    - {name: lv-root, volgroup: lvm-volgroup-vg-0, size: 100%, preserve: false,
      type: lvm_partition, id: lvm-partition-lv-root}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm-partition-lv-root, preserve: false, type: format,
      id: format-1}
    - {device: format-1, path: /, type: mount, id: mount-2}
    - {device: format-0, path: /boot, type: mount, id: mount-1}
    - {device: format-2, path: /boot/efi, type: mount, id: mount-3}
```

It looks like the float bug *may* have been fixed with this commit and might be avoided if the automatic installer update feature is used

https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/subiquity/commit/8a84e470c59e292138482a0b1bd7144fbb4644db#diff-1ca44bce35f59e931cbe850119e630db

Answer (score 2):

Negative size does work.  2nd partition is set to size -1 and uses all available space.

```
  storage:
    config:
    - grub_device: true
      id: disk-sda
      path: /dev/sda
      ptable: gpt
      type: disk
      wipe: superblock-recursive
    - device: disk-sda
      flag: bios_grub
      id: partition-0
      number: 1
      size: 1048576
      type: partition
    - device: disk-sda
      id: partition-1
      number: 2
      size: -1
      type: partition
      wipe: superblock
    - fstype: ext4
      id: format-0
      type: format
      volume: partition-1
    - device: format-0
      id: mount-0
      path: /
      type: mount
```

Comment: negative size work on the last partition only