# curtin script: set size as remaining space on disk

Tags: partitioning, maas, preseed, curtin

I am using maas 2.9 on ubuntu 20.04 server os to install ubuntu 20.04 images.

**Issue 1: how to create last partition with remaining space?**

To create a custom storage configuration, I have added the following code:

```
 storage:
    version: 1
    config:
      - id: sda
        type: disk
        wipe: superblock
        ptable: gpt
        model: VOLUME1 DISK
        serial: 5000c500bbe76fab
        grub_device: true
# Create a partition for boot
      - id: sda1
        type: partition
        size: 3G
        device: sda
        name: boot-partition
        wipe: superblock
      - id: sda-boot
        type: format
        fstype: ext4
        label: BOOT
# Get volume name from partition id
        volume: sda1
#Mount this on boot
      - id: sda1-mount
        type: mount
        path: /boot
#Get device name from format id
        device: sda-boot
#Create partition for boot efi
      - id: sda2
        type: partition
        size: 500M
        device: sda
        name: bootefi-partition
        wipe: superblock
      - id: sda-bootefi
        type: format
        fstype: fat32
        label: BOOTEFI
        volume: sda2
#Mount this on boot
      - id: sda2-mount
        type: mount
        path: /boot/efi
        device: sda-bootefi
#Create partition for usr
      - id: sda3
        type: partition
        size: 20G
        device: sda
        name: usr-partition
        wipe: superblock
      - id: sda-usr
        type: format
        fstype: xfs
        label: USR
        volume: sda3
#Mount this on usr
      - id: sda3-mount
        type: mount
        path: /usr
        device: sda-usr
#Create partition for TMP
      - id: sda4
        type: partition
        size: 5G
        device: sda
        name: tmp-partition
        wipe: superblock
      - id: sda-tmp
        type: format
        fstype: xfs
        label: TMP
        volume: sda4
#Mount this on tmp
      - id: sda4-mount
        type: mount
        path: /tmp
        device: sda-tmp
#Create partition for ROOT
      - id: sda5
        type: partition
        size: 50G
        device: sda
        name: root-partition
        wipe: superblock
        flag: boot
      - id: sda-root
        type: format
        fstype: xfs
        label: ROOT
        volume: sda5
#Mount this on /
      - id: sda5-mount
        type: mount
        path: /
        device: sda-root
#Create partition for HOME
      - id: sda6
        type: partition
        size: 50G
        device: sda
        name: home-partition
        wipe: superblock
      - id: sda-home
        type: format
        fstype: xfs
        label: HOME
        volume: sda6
#Mount this on /home
      - id: sda6-mount
        type: mount
        path: /home
        device: sda-home
#Create partition for VAR
      - id: sda7
        type: partition
        size: -1
        device: sda
        name: var-partition
        wipe: superblock
#Format partition for var
      - id: sda-var
        type: format
        fstype: xfs
        label: VAR
        volume: sda7
#Mount this on var
      - id: sda7-mount
        type: mount
        path: /var
        device: sda-var
```

I am getting the following error:

```
     previous partition number for 'sda7' found to be '7'
        partition_kname=sda7
        previous partition: /sys/class/block/sda/sda7 size_sectors=104857600 start_sectors=164605952
        adding partition 'sda7' to disk 'sda' (ptable: 'gpt')
        partnum: 8 offset_sectors: 269463552 length_sectors: -1
        Preparing partition location on disk /dev/sda
        Wiping 1M on /dev/sda at offset 137965338624
        Running command ['sgdisk', '--new', '8:269463552:269463551', '--typecode=8:8300', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
        An error occured handling 'sda7': ProcessExecutionError - Unexpected error while running command.
        Command: ['sgdisk', '--new', '8:269463552:269463551', '--typecode=8:8300', '/dev/sda']
        Exit code: 4
        Reason: -
        Stdout: ''
        Stderr: Could not create partition 8 from 269463552 to 269463551
                Could not change partition 8's type code to 8300!
                Error encountered; not saving changes.
                
        finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: FAIL: configuring partition: sda7
        TIMED BLOCK_META: 23.273
        finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: FAIL: curtin command block-meta
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/curtin/curtin/commands/main.py", line 202, in main
            ret = args.func(args)
          File "/curtin/curtin/log.py", line 97, in wrapper
            return log_time("TIMED %s: " % msg, func, *args, **kwargs)
          File "/curtin/curtin/log.py", line 79, in log_time
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
          File "/curtin/curtin/commands/block_meta.py", line 111, in block_meta
            return meta_custom(args)
          File "/curtin/curtin/commands/block_meta.py", line 1916, in meta_custom
            handler(command, storage_config_dict)
          File "/curtin/curtin/commands/block_meta.py", line 934, in partition_handler
            util.subp(cmd, capture=True)
          File "/curtin/curtin/util.py", line 275, in subp
            return _subp(*args, **kwargs)
          File "/curtin/curtin/util.py", line 139, in _subp
            raise ProcessExecutionError(stdout=out, stderr=err,
        curtin.util.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
        Command: ['sgdisk', '--new', '8:269463552:269463551', '--typecode=8:8300', '/dev/sda']
        Exit code: 4
        Reason: -
        Stdout: ''
        Stderr: Could not create partition 8 from 269463552 to 269463551
                Could not change partition 8's type code to 8300!
                Error encountered; not saving changes.
                
        Unexpected error while running command.
        Command: ['sgdisk', '--new', '8:269463552:269463551', '--typecode=8:8300', '/dev/sda']
        Exit code: 4
        Reason: -
        Stdout: ''
        Stderr: Could not create partition 8 from 269463552 to 269463551
                Could not change partition 8's type code to 8300!
                Error encountered; not saving changes.
```

Can someone please tell me what value should I provide for size field?

**Issue 2: If I define the last partition size as a fixed value, the OS installs successfully. But during first boot, /root partition could not be found**

The error is somewhat like follows:

```
/usr clean mount ok
/root/lib : mkdir failed
/sbin/ : not found
```

Thanks

Comment: So long as `sda7` is the final partition on the storage device, `-1` should work. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1244571/1091774) goes into greater detail for what worked in different scenarios, but I'm not seeing anything wrong with your config. Are you seeing an error message?

Comment: @Matigo  ,sorry for the late reply. I have now pasted the complete code. If I am entering a fixed size for /var, I am able to install the OS successfully at boot it is not able to find / partition. Can you please verify the code? I am not able to find much help on curtin online